# Usage of not only...but also

Tags: meaning

> Not only benefit students who actually take part in sports, spectators also learn about loyalty and encouragement and sportsmanship in face of defeat.

I`m not sure whether this expression is correct.

Comment: I've answered the question about the phrase, but to improve or explain your example sentence, it is unclear who the subject of the benefit is, the spectators or the players?

Comment: Please give a complete example in context.

Comment: What I want to express is that both the students and the spectators benefit from the sports activities. The previous sentence describes how the students who play the sports benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not only [A]...but (also) [B]** is called a *correlative conjunction*.

It expressed emphasis or surprise for what you are listing.

[A] is well known and unsurprising, but [B] is not well known and surprisingly as true in the sentence as [A].

The phrase can be **"Not only...but also..."** or **"Not only...but..."**
So "also" is the optional word in the phrase.

Your example is incorrect because the phrase needs a "but".

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion! Here is my revised version "Not only the students who play the sports benefit, but the spectators also learn about loyalty and encouragement as well as sportsmanship in the face of defeat." Is it right now?

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense now. Small edit (add "do"): "Not only do the students who play the sports benefit, but the spectators also learn about loyalty and encouragement as well as sportsmanship in the face of defeat."

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic phrasing would be:

> Spectator sports benefit not only the active participants, but also the spectators, who witness the importance of loyalty and sportsmanship in both victory and defeat.

Comment: It`s very kind of you. That makes perfect sense:)